# Eliminate duplicate code whose only difference is the type

Tags: scala

I have two structurally-equivalent class pairs whose only difference is the types.  I would like to be able to merge `V1` with `V2` and `K1` with `K2`.  I control those four classes, but I am not able to modify `takesDoublesOrLists` - it comes from a library.

```
class V1 (
    val a: Double,
    val b: Double,
    // ...
    val z: Double
)

class K1(v: V1) {
    def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}

class V2 (
    val a: List[Double],
    val b: List[Double],
    // ...
    val z: List[Double]
)

class K2(v: V2) {
    def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}
```

I tried following the [type class pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790980/how-do-i-setup-multiple-ored-type-bounds-in-scala), but got an error that the overloaded method `takesDoublesOrLists` could not be applied to my type parameter.

**Edit:**

The signature of the overloaded function `takesDoublesOrLists` is as the name suggests:

```
def takesDoublesOrLists(a: Double, b: Double, /* ..., */ z: Double): Something = /* ... */
def takesDoublesOrLists(a: List[Double], b: List[Double], /* ..., */ z: List[Double]): Something = /* ... */
```

Comment: can you share the signature of `takesDoublesOrLists`?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836769/type-parameterization-in-scala

Comment: @TzachZohar: added in my edit above.

Comment: What is preventing you from having just a K and a V class, since they are exactly the same (at least from your code)...?

Comment: @ericbn: they are not: in V1, every val is a `Double`, and in V2, they are all of type `List[Double]`, and `takesDoublesOrLists` needs to know this type.

Comment: It seems to me that things would be much simpler if `takesDoublesOrLists` accepted a `List[X]` where `X` were either `Double` or `List[Double]`. I'm afraid it's impossible, and different overloads of `takesDoublesOrLists` are chosen statically at compile time, thus making a "generic" call impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I can see how you could merge `V1` and `V2`, but not `K1` or `K2`:

```
class V[T] (
  val a: T,
  val b: T
  // ...
  val z: T
)

class K1(v: V[Double]) {
  def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}

class K2(v: V[List[Double]]) {
  def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}
```

**EDIT:** If your K1 and K2 classes are more complex than what you exemplified, you could break this behavior with traits:

```
trait KDoubles {
  def v: V[Double]
  def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}

trait KLists {
  def v: V[List[Double]]
  def doIt = takesDoublesOrLists(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}

class K {
  // common stuff ...
}

class K1 extends K with KDoubles {
  // ...
}

class K2 extends K with KLists {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, so have an upvote.  Worth it if nothing else is possible, but `K1` and `K2` are much more complicated than `V` and are the bigger aim for me - I just boiled them down to one function to demonstrate the core of the problem.

Comment: @Nate, updated my answer. We would need more info about K1 and K2 to be able to better reason about them...

Comment: A good point.  Unfortunately, distilling a problem is an inexact science.  In my case, `takesDoublesOrLists` is a stand in for a few functions that are used rampantly throughout every part of `K1` and `K2`.  I figured my example was enough to capture the core of my problem without introducing distractions.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried following the type class pattern, but got an error that the overloaded method takesDoublesOrLists could not be applied to my type parameter.

You don't show your attempt, but you shouldn't be calling the overloaded version of `takesDoublesOrLists`, it should be part of the typeclass (of course, you can call the existing version when implementing it, if there are reasons not to move the implementation there):

```
sealed trait DoubleOrList[A] {
  def doIt(a: A, b: A, /* ..., */ z: A): Something
}

object DoubleOrList {
  implicit object DoubleIsDoubleOrList extends DoubleOrList[Double] {
    def doIt(a: Double, b: Double, /* ..., */ z: Double): Something = 
      SomeObject.takesDoublesOrLists(a, b, z)
  }
  implicit object ListIsDoubleOrList extends DoubleOrList[List[Double]] { 
    def doIt(a: List[Double], b: List[Double], /* ..., */ z: List[Double]): Something = 
      SomeObject.takesDoublesOrLists(a, b, z)
  }
}

// this context bound isn't really necessary, but it prevents you from creating V[String] you can't use
class V[A: DoubleOrList](
  val a: A,
  val b: A,
  // ...
  val z: A
)

class K[A](v: V[A])(implicit dOrL: DoubleOrList[A]) {
  def doIt = dOrL.doIt(v.a, v.b, /* ..., */ v.z)
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the trouble, I think: `takesDoublesOrLists` is not a member of a typeclass.  The typeclass I made was empty, and just used as a restriction in `V` and `K`.  `takesDoublesOrLists` is code that I don't control.  If I took it into the typeclass, I'd be right back where I started.

Comment: As I said, in this case the implementations of `takesDoublesOrLists` in the typeclass instances should call the ones you don't control. I've edited and changed the name of the typeclass method to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, I understood from your original example.  I wasn't clear when I wrote I'd be back where I started; I meant that I would have just moved the complexity of having two implementations for `K` out one layer, to having two nearly-duplicate implementations of the typeclass.  It is probably about equal in terms of character count.  I'm debating if it's a simpler solution.